# Why is the print show() showing not defined?

Tags: python, class, oop, linked-list, nodes

I used my pydroid to create a linkedlist, but the show() is outputting "nameError: name show not defined". Please any answer to why the error. The show() is to help me print out my added data from the add()

```
class Node:
    next=None
    data=None
    
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        
        
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        
    def Empty(self):
            return self.head==None
        
    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count=0
        while current:
            count +=1
            current = current.next
        return count
        
"""i want to be able to show data i add to the list wit the add()"""    
    def Show(self):
            n= self.head
            while n:
                print(n.data)
                n = n.next
            else:
                print("empty")
                
#the add()              
    def add(self, data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head =new_node
        

b=LinkedList()
#a = Node(10)
#b.head=a
b.add(3)
b.add(3)
b.add(3)
print(b.size())
print(Show())
```

Comment: Did you forget the `b.`?

Comment: And surely you meant: `b.Show()`, not `print(b.Show())`.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I ommitted the b.show

Comment: Thanks, worked without the print function.

Answer (score 0):

Print is unnecessary, just use what is listed below:

```
b.show()
```

***credit @quamerana***